# UPI ID type not allowed on google pay

Tags: google-pay, upi

I am trying to set up online payment using google pay API on a website.
I set up google pay business account. Then I tried to verify UPI id but I get an error `UPI ID type not allowed`

[image]

Comment: i am facing same problem, here i am using my personal UPI ID; let me know if you are able to resolve this

Comment: I decided to go with stripe